# Bootsrap vertical carousel chrome and IE

Tags: .net, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, umbraco, carousel

I have a problem with the bootstrap vertical carousel on Chrome and IE but not in Firefox.
in Firefox it's working great!

the problem is - when i'm click on "next" slide the contents are change but not in the way it's change in Firefox and in the way it should.

i try to do a vertical slider - please get in the link http://maholshalem.bioserver.co.il/ and see the content slider down the "UPCOMING EVENTS" and click on the red button calls "more" to see how it work on Firefox and how it works on Chrome..

really thanks for the helpers :)

here is my code if it helps you to help me:

```
<!-- MainProductionHomePage -->
<div class="caption-button caption-gray left-top" style="font-size:14px;">UPCOMING EVENTS</div>
<div class="padding-top-60">
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
    <!-- slider start here -->
    <div id="eventCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical" >
    <div class="carousel-inner" style="min-height:800px;">
@{
     <!-- get the content for the slider -->
    var content = Umbraco.Content(xxxx);

    int itemsCount = content.Children.Count();
    int sliders = itemsCount % 5;
    int currSlider = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= sliders; i++)
    {
        var items = content.Children;

        if (i == 0)
        {
            @Html.Raw("<div class=\"item active\">")
            items = content.Children.Take(5);
        }
        else
        {
            items = content.Children.Skip(i * 5).Take(5);
            @Html.Raw("<div class=\"item\">")
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var contentService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService.GetById(int.Parse(item.Id.ToString()));

            var image = Umbraco.Media(contentService.Properties["smallThumbnail"].Value.ToString());
            var imageUrl = image.url;

            var date = (DateTime)contentService.Properties["date"].Value;
            var name = contentService.Properties["name"].Value;
            var description = contentService.Properties["fullText"].Value;
            var themeColor = contentService.Properties["themeColor"].Value;
            var shortDescription = contentService.Properties["shortText"].Value;
            var itemUrl = String.Format("production/{0}", item.name.ToString().Replace(" ", "-"));

            // IF Iteration HERE
            <div class="row custom">
                <!-- DATE -->
                <div style="float:left;" onclick="location.href='@itemUrl';">
                    <!-- PRODUCTION Image -->
                    <div class="event-thumb col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 no-wrap-col">
                        <img src="@imageUrl" class="production-image" style="cursor:pointer;" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- End PRODUCTION  Image -->
                    <div class="event-list col-md-2 col-sm-3 no-wrap-col" >
                        <div>
                            <time datetime="2014-07-20 0000">
                                <span class="date" style="background-color:#@themeColor !important;">@date.ToString("dd.MM")</span>
                                <span class="day" style="background-color:#@themeColor !important;">@date.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper()</span>
                                <span class="background-white"  style="color:#@themeColor !important;">
                                    <span class="hour">@date.ToString("HH:mm")</span>
                                </span>
                            </time>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END DATE -->
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-5 no-wrap-col">
                        <div class="homepage-production-title">
                            <a href="~/@itemUrl" style="color:#@themeColor">@name.ToString().ToUpper()</a>
                        </div><span class="production-description">
                            @MvcHtmlString.Create(shortDescription.ToString().Length > 150 ? shortDescription.ToString().Substring(0, 150) : shortDescription).. 
                            <a href="~/@itemUrl" style="color:#@themeColor">Read more</a>
                            </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
             @Html.Raw("</div>")
    }
}                   
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    @if (itemsCount > 5)
    {
        <a class="caption-button caption-red right-bottom" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="next">MORE</a>
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Completely off topic, but you should not use the ContentService.  The content service will hit the database instead of the content Cache.  Try to use the current model on the view (using @CurrentPage or @Model.Content).  This will make your pages much faster.

Comment: thank you my friend, I will fix it. I realy apriciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

More Info Here :

Bootstrap 3 : **https://github.com/tutorialdrive/Bootstrap-3-Vertical-Thumbnail-Carousel**

Bootstrap 2 : **https://github.com/tutorialdrive/Bootstrap-Vertical-Thumbnail-Carousel**

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <table>
          <tr>
            <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/1.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/2.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/3.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/4.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
        </div><!--/row-fluid-->
    </div><!--/item-->

    <div class="item">
        <div class="row-fluid">
           <table>
              <tr>
                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/5.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/6.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/7.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/8.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
        </div><!--/row-fluid-->
    </div><!--/item-->

    <div class="item">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/9.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/10.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/11.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/12.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div><!--/row-fluid-->
    </div><!--/item-->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually stumbled into the exact same problem a couple of days ago. I have narrowed it down to however Chrome manages *.carousel* and *.carousel-inner* classes.

If you set your *.vertical .active.left* to the exact height of your carousel and left:100% it "fixes" the problem for Chrome, while Firefox starts doing the same thing. I'll leave a couple of images for whoever can help us and keep you posted.

Notice how Chrome (first image) takes the *.active.left* element 100% to the left, while Firefox keeps it aligned with the container's left border (*.active.left* originally has a left value of zero).

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzRV8.png) - [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl5I6.png)

Hopes this helps help us ;)

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, please do not use answers as a workaround.